# Name Resolution of TRUNCATE TABLE in SQL Server 2008 R2 vs SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

We experienced an error in our code that was executed in SQL Server 2014 which we do not encounter in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Our code is like this:

```
IF EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
WHERE name = N'WebDB'
)
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE [WebDB].[dbo].[webtable] 
END
```

The Truncate Table command will only execute if the WebDB exists. In SQL Server 2008 R2, this code runs without any problems. In SQL Server 2014, there is a problem that when the WebDB doesn't exist, it will throw an error saying that 'Database 'WebDB' does not exist.'. It is doing name resolution of the TRUNCATE TABLE command prior to the actual execution.

Can someone explain this change in behaviour for SQL Server 2014?

Comment: Thanks for the replies Eralper and PSK. If someone knows if SQL Server 2014 can be forced to behave like SQL 2008 with regards to this, that would also be helpful.

Comment: Out of interest, what is/was the compatibility level of the database you're executing this query in on the SQL Server 2008 R2 server? (That is, not `WebDB`, but whatever this query executed in -- if `master`, the compatibility level is obviously `100`, but a user DB could have set this lower). I ask because this is the kind of behavior I'd expect from SQL Server 2000, but not 2005 or later.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert I was able to reproduce it on SQL Server 2005, compatibility level = 90

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert But the same query on 2012 with compatibility level = 90 throws the error

Comment: @sepupic: Thanks, that means it's definitely not related to the deferred compilation changes introduced in SQL Server 2005, but a different change that happened in 2012. I don't recall having read anything about it as an intended change, which may mean not enough people in production were relying on this for MS to consider it a problem. (Or my memory of all the changes is just failing me, which is also very possible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Actually the problem is because the existence of the database is
>   evaluated when parsing the script, before running it. All statements
>   are parsed independently of the condition for their execution.

This is something which was not being done in SQL 2008.

Anyway you can update your query as following.

```
IF EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
WHERE [name] = N'WebDB'
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @T NVARCHAR(1000)
    SET @T = N'TRUNCATE TABLE [WebDB].[dbo].[webtable]'
    EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @T 

END
```

This is not the `SSMS` behavior, this change has been done in the core, even if you run your query using `SQLCMD` you will observe the same behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the reply PSK. Yes, it is not name resolution but the evaluation when parsing the script before running it. Is there a way to force the SQL Server 2014 behaviour to be like SQL 2008? We would prefer not to update the code unless absolutely necessary since that would entail additional development.

Comment: I doubt, even changing COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL will not help

Comment: I tried setting the Compatibility Level to SQL Server 2008, but as guessed it did not help for getting the same response

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Editor parses the code without any error but in runtime the SQL Engine throws error

I cannot explain the reason for change in behaviour but you can convert your sample code into dynamic SQL and execute with sp_executeSQL command as follows

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = N'WebDB'
)
BEGIN
    declare @sql nvarchar(100) = N'TRUNCATE TABLE [WebDB].[dbo].[webtable]'
    exec sp_executeSql @sql
END
```